# Преобразование данных txt файла в словарь

Tags: python

Имеется txt файл со следующим содержимым:

Чемпионат:
Один против дюжины. 2000 год

Дата:
00-000-2000

Тур:
Тур 34

Вопрос 1:
С одним советским туристом...

Ответ:
За то...

Автор:
Максим Поташев

Вопрос 2:
В своем первоначально...

Ответ:
Батарея (от battre).

Источник:
СЭС

Автор:
Вадим Карлинский

и т.д.

Требуется поместить в словарь только данные начинающиеся со слов "Вопрос" и "Ответ"
Пример:

```
[
{Вопрос 1: С одним советским туристом в Марселе произошел такой случай...,
Ответ:За то, что...},
{Вопрос 1: В своем первоначально узком...,
Ответ: Батарея (от battre).},
]
```

Не могу понять как то сделать пробовал следующее:

```
    quiz_dict = {}
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding="KOI8-R") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == '':
                continue
            if line.startswith('Вопрос'):
                question_number = line.split(' ')[1].strip()
                quiz_dict[f"Вопрос({question_number})"] = ""
            elif line.startswith('Ответ'):
                quiz_dict[f"Вопрос({question_number})"] += line.split(':')[1].strip() + '\n'

    print(quiz_dict)


Выходит ерунда какая-то.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извлекает данные из файла `file.txt`, начиная с ключевых слов "Вопрос" и "Ответ", и сохраняет их в список словарей `result`.

P.S. Можете считывать файл построчно, особенно если файл слишком большой, чтобы его целиком загрузить в память

```
import re

# Открываем файл и читаем его
with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = file.read()
# Используем регулярные выражения для извлечения данных вопросов и ответов
matches = re.findall(r'Вопрос \d+:.*?Ответ:.*?(?:Автор:|Источник:|$)', data, re.DOTALL)
# Создаем список словарей с данными вопросов и ответов
result = []
for match in matches:
    question_match = re.search(r'Вопрос \d+:(.*?)Ответ:', match, re.DOTALL)
    answer_match = re.search(r'Ответ:(.*?)(?:Автор:|Источник:|$)', match, re.DOTALL)   
    if question_match and answer_match:
        question = question_match.group(1).strip()
        answer = answer_match.group(1).strip()
        result.append({"Вопрос": question, "Ответ": answer})
# Выводим полученные данные
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!